# How to store the multiple structures instances in shared memory?

Tags: c, unix, posix, shared-memory

I have a struct definition as follows

```
struct s
{
int a;
};
struct s s1;
struct s s2;
```

I need to push both structure instances to shared memory.

```
char *data=(char *)shmat(m_sharedMemoryId,NULL,0);
memcpy(data,&s1,sizeof struct s);
```

I did for the 1st instance of structure.

How to do for the second instance? Is this possible in shared memory?

Plaftform : UNIX

Comment: @iharob is this will overwrite first instance?

Comment: `memcpy(data + sizeof(struct s), &s2, sizeof(struct s));` if you want the `s2` struct direct behind `s1` in the same shm.

Comment: @mch Goodness. Is there is any other way to acheive this? Because i have to keep track how many instances pushed to insert the new one.

Comment: it's just a plain array... use a counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shmat` calls only gets a pointer to a shared memory segment that should have previously be created with `shmget`. You have 2 ways to deal with that :

- allocate a segment that will hold an array for all your structs and then copy your structs to this array :

  ```
  m_sharedMemoryId = shmget(key, sizeof(struct s) * nb, perm_flag);
  struct s* data = shmat(m_sharedMemoryId,NULL,0);
  ```

  and then you copy a struct s where you want in the array, here in position i :

  ```
  memcpy(data + i,&s1,sizeof(struct s));
  ```

  this is mainly to use if you have many little structures
- allocate a different segment per each struct

  ```
  m_sharedMemoryId = shmget(key, sizeof(struct s), perm_flag);
  struct s* data = shmat(m_sharedMemoryId,NULL,0);
  memcpy(data,&s1,sizeof(struct s));
  ```

  and you repeat the allocation for each struct. This is to use if you have few big structs that you want to be able to deallocate separately

Comment: if `shmat()` returns `void *` and this is c why do you cast to `struct s *`?

Comment: @iharob: no harm done. it also shows how to access it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I am not saying it's wrong just wondering why to do it.